# Can't add items to ArrayList that store inside class

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I should to use addList, setList and getList when need in fragment. But I can't add item to list. It is 0 size in always. Why can not do this?

RequestFragment.kt

```
                UploadedImageTokenRepository().addItemTitleList("ImageName1.jpg")
                UploadedImageTokenRepository().getTitleList()
```

UploadedImageTokenRepository.kt

```
 class UploadedImageTokenRepository {
        private var imgTitleList: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
    
        fun getTitleList(): ArrayList<String> {
            return imgTitleList
        }
    
        fun addItemTitleList(title: String) {
            imgTitleList.add(title)
        }
    
        fun setItemTitleList(title: String, itemPosition: Int) {
            imgTitleList[itemPosition] = title
        }
    
        fun clearTitleList() {
            imgTitleList = arrayListOf()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `UploadedImageTokenRepository()` creates a new instance of the repository. So you have two repositories each with their own list. Instead, you need to create a single repository object that you can use repeatedly.

Comment: Can you write code of it please?

Comment: You need to declare a variable to store a reference to the object so you can reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines according to @Code-Apprentice reply.

```
 private val uploadedImageTokenRepository: UploadedImageTokenRepository = UploadedImageTokenRepository()

            uploadedImageTokenRepository.addItemTitleList("ImageName1.jpg")
            uploadedImageTokenRepository.getTitleList()
```